# Ansible Loop STDOUT format

Tags: format, stdout

I have ansible playbook, where I am getting output from loop. But the output all in one line.

- name: Output the results
  debug: msg="{{ mq_channel_output.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') |  list) }}"

Output

```
        "5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2022.\nStarting MQSC for queue manager MQ310.\n\n\n     1 : dis chs(*)\nAMQ8420I: Channel Status not found.\nOne MQSC command read.\nNo commands have a syntax error.\nOne valid MQSC command could not be processed."
    ],
```

What I want output to print each line separately. Like this

" 5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2022.
Starting MQSC for queue manager MQ310.

```
 1 : dis chs(*)
```

AMQ8420I: Channel Status not found.
One MQSC command read.
No commands have a syntax error.
One valid MQSC command could not be processed."

Answer (score 0):

Fix it, using join
`{{ mq_channel_output.results |map(attribute='stdout_lines') | join('\n') }}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).